Answer was deleted by drive-by moderator
https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/152581/129071

Answer was deleted without understanding the question and context.
Instead of flagging, deletion was used, the most harsh way of punishment. As if it was  some spam links posted.
Deletion does not provide an opportunity to reply. Rewriting the answer and being at the mercy of that moderator is the only option. Knowing that the moderation action was disproportionate, and that the updated answer may also be moderated in the same way, makes the contributor very sceptical about contributing again.


A link isn't an answer. If there is useful information relevant to the question found behind those links then you should summarise the information, explain why it is relevant and correct and then use the links only as citations. Please amend this post accordingly

The question was about examples of software. It is not realistic to expect an answer with presentation slides of examples of such software, as I am providing the answer in my free time.
I have not provided "just links," and I understand the frustration when people post links as "mystery meat" answers without context. I provided context for the links I posted, knowing that this is a very specific area and that very few examples can be found, as evidenced by the lack of other answers to that question.
Moderator acted too harsh and stereotypical of toxic behaviour that goes  against the spirit of the community.

The timeline of events on that post were:
(Times are UTC)
Oct 16 at 14:28:    Moderator comment added: 'This isn't an answer to the question, it's just some links. A link isn't an answer. If there is useful information relevant to the question found behind those links then you should summarise the information, explain why it is relevant and correct and then use the links only as citations. Please amend this post accordingly.'

Oct 16 at 14:28:    Notice added "Needs detailed answers"

Oct 17 at 9:42:     Deletion

So the post wasn't just automatically deleted. A comment and a notice were applied to it and the answer remained up and visible until the next day. At that point no amendments to the answer had been made so it was deleted.
You can amend any of your own deleted answers to address the points raised, and then flag it for undeletion. However all that you have done is just flag it for undeletion without making the requested amendments, so it has not been reinstated.
There is no reasoning in that answer, no detail about what is being linked to in those URLs, no examples, no commentary on why anything behind those links are useful solutions to the problem stated. It's just 'go and look at these links'
Here is a post on the main Meta StackExchange site covering off why such answers are not suitable - and why moderators are expected to remove them if they are not improved: Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?
And here is another example from the same place: Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?

I think that there is a difference between how a moderator would deal with someone who is new to StackExchange versus someone who has obviously been in the community and is familiar with the standards and expectations. Some would argue that this is no different to the type of treatment that you would get on other platforms like Reddit (except it might be done by a bot instead), and I think that in the past when I have simply placed comments against similar questions but not deleted them, I usually end up having to do it in the end.
From the interactions that I have had with other moderators on UXSE and other StackExchange sites, the consensus seems to be that it is important to maintain the standards and guidelines of StackExchange so that it can be better differentiated from other online Q&A forums. UXSE has its own idiosyncrasy as well, but that's why there are other UX related forums for those types of questions and answers.
I do think that there can be a better experience for the users, but until moderators are given better tools and resources to do so, we try to moderate within the standards and guidelines as best as we can, since we are also just trying to moderate in our free time. We try to live up to the spirit and intent as much as we can, but moderation by humans remain as much of an art as it is an imprecise science, especially since there are an abundance of AI-generated content to deal with as well.

Can you please point me to an example of an answer to such a question, asking for examples of software? What would be acceptable in such case?

I had a quick look and these are two examples that give you an idea of the types of answers we might expect from questions asking for examples: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/48389/what-is-an-example-of-a-mobile-app-using-an-eye-icon-for-showing-the-password-in and https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/148705/components-in-graph-based-ui-with-more-complex-interactions

It is likely that the person asking the question would find the information provided useful. It is a specific niche question, which makes the answer more valuable. Evident from the lack of other answers to the question.
The information was removed not because of its usefulness, but because the suitability of information is judged by its presentation and volume, which are measured by adherence to a requirement that is not disclosed at the time of posting.
It was pointed out that I, the poster, am responsible for knowing that requirement, and if I have been a contributor for a long time, it is even more my fault.
I suppose that even with 15 more years of participation, I would still not be aware of the requirement.
Could it be that removal without recourse and consultation was designed for spam posts and this is a misuse of it?

Why I did not provide answer according to guidelines?

In order to provide an answer with screenshots, I would have to download and install that software, which is not realistic.
I am not sure what else can be described about the heatmap UI.
If I were seeking such information, I would prefer to see a short answer with a link rather than no answer at all.
I was not aware of the reply requirements.


Please
 A straightforward solution would be to place such an answer under an expandable outline with a warning that it does not adhere to submission rules, but in the interest of information exchange, it can be viewed.
 The information regarding answer requirements could be displayed while the answer post is being created.
 Deletion is akin to capital punishment; bad UX, it creates negative associations.
